# Laravel - why new model is not loaded in the app?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, model

I started to develop simple Laravel app.

Created a few routes, views and it works.

Now - wanted to create menu. Made Navbar model and surprise. It's not loaded in the framework.

When debugging, classMap generated in findFile($class) function seems to have my model not loaded/broken. [image: Navbar not loaded.]

My model's file is app/Models/Navbar.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Navbar extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'route', 'ordering'
    ];
}
```

I want to use this model in boot() section of AppServiceProvider (app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Navbar;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
        View::composer('demo', function ($view) {
            $nb = new Navbar();
            $navbars = $nb::all();
            $view->with('navbar', $navbars);
        });
    }
}
```

Cache clearing, dumping autoloads etc. does not seem to help at all.

As a result when trying to use my model I am getting error like:

`include(/var/www): Failed to open stream: Success`

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the issue is in the AppServiceProvider, remove the initialization of Navbar, and just have $navbars = Navbar::all(), this is the "recommend practice" when using Laravel Models

Comment: Hello @dz0nika. Thanks for replying.
I think firstly I used it in this way, the same result and that's why I started to try another way of calling it. I think problem is deeper but cannot understand it.
Btw - does Laravel load models dynamically or the map always should has all stuff loaded?

Comment: Can you share more details, like the error message in text form? Also, how is your problem related to Composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase
Last three stack calls:

vendor / laravel / framework / src / Illuminate / Events / Dispatcher.php : 421
`return $listener(...array_values($payload));`
--
vendor / laravel / framework / src / Illuminate / Events / Dispatcher.php : 249
`$response = $listener($event, $payload);`
--
vendor / laravel / framework / src / Illuminate / View / Concerns / ManagesEvents.php : 177
    `public function callComposer(ViewContract $view) { $this->events->dispatch('composing: '.$view->name(), [$view]); }`

Comment: Final error is in the question: `include(/var/www): Failed to open stream: Success`.
According to composer: Seems laravel uses something called composer to compose it's views. Just names coincidence. Removed this tag.

Comment: Where's the code that triggers this "final error"? How could "Success" be an error?

Comment: @NicoHaase If I knew I would not ask here how success could be an error for laravel.
Seems that the line that throws this exception is vendor / composer / ClassLoader.php : 571
`function includeFile($file) { include $file; }`

Seems that because in the classMap it has wrong string (attached image), the `includeFile()` function tries to load main path. 

Crazy.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and add all relevant information in text form (not hinting in a screenshot). Does your composer.json contain any hints about that special class?

Comment: Crazy stuff: Created new model (the same as old one) by artisan and magically it started to work. No idea what was wrong.
But I understand now why Error had "success" description at least. It's fault of PHP itself. The description of warning when you will include dir path (not file's one) is: `Warning: include(/dir/path): Failed to open stream: Success in /path/to/file.php on line X`